# How to add multiple images to Firebase realtime database using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload images to realtime firebase database. I made it with one images but I have no idea how to add multiple images.

This is my solution for one image.

```
<v-layout row>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
            <!-- accept nam govori da uzme slike i nista vise-->
            <v-btn raised @click="onPickFile">Upload image</v-btn>
            <input
              type="file"
              style="display:none"
              ref="fileInput"
              accept="image/*"
              @change="onFilePicked"/></v-flex
        ></v-layout>
```

In data I have this two: imgURL: "",
      image: null
And this is a method:

```
onFilePicked(event) {
  //files is list of imaages by puting files[0] we are taking just one
  const files = event.target.files;
  let filename = files[0].name;
  if (filename.lastIndexOf(".") <= 0) {
    return alert("Please add a valid file!");
  }
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    this.imgURL = fileReader.result;
  });
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  this.image = files[0];
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, this is not a firebase related question, but I try to help anyway:

First of all, you should add `multiple` to the input-tag, so you can select more than only one file there:

```html
// CHANGE THIS:
<input type="file" style="display:none" ref="fileInput" accept="image/*" @change="onFilePicked"/>
// TO THIS:
<input type="file" style="display:none" ref="fileInput" accept="image/*" @change="onFilePicked" multiple/>
```

I assume you stumbled upon this wierd 'for-loop' for the files.. I had the same issue and figured out when I type `of` instead of `in`, then I get the file itself, not just the index and there is no error.

I splitted up the main parts of your function and converted them in asyncron `Promises` (because there might be a timing error with the `addEventListener`)

This is just the idea of the multiple files upload. Maybe you should add some more error-catcher:

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    blobs: [],
    images: [],
  },
  methods: {
    async onFilePicked(event) {
      const files = event.target.files
      this.images =[]
      this.blobs =[]
      for (let file of files) {
        this.images.push(file)
        let blob = await this.prepareImagesForUpload(file)
        this.blobs.push(blob)
      }
      this.uploadImagesToFirebase()
    },
    prepareImagesForUpload(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let filename = file.name
        if (filename.lastIndexOf(".") <= 0) {
          alert("Please add a valid file: ", filename)
          reject()
        }
        const fileReader = new FileReader()
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
        fileReader.addEventListener("load", async () => {resolve(fileReader.result)})
      })
    },
    uploadImagesToFirebase() {
      //... do the firebase upload magic with:
      console.log(this.blobs)
      //...
    }
  }
})
```